# React Native - Dynamic State? Or equivalent solution

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to build a view which displays alarm codes - these are delivered to the app in a data array as follows:

**`alarm:[{ location: "Main Door", code:"123456"}, { location: "Back Door", code:"456789"}],`**

For each instance there could be 1 or many codes.

I am displaying the codes via this map function:

```
return this.state.alarmsOnSite.map((data, index) => {

  return (
    <View key={index}>
    <Text style={GlobalStyles.SubHeading}>
      Alarm: {data.location}
    </Text>

      <View style={[GlobalStyles.GreyBox, {position:'relative'}]}>
        <Text style={GlobalStyles.starText}>
        ********
        </Text>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={CheckInStyles.eyeballImagePlacement}
        >
          <View style={CheckInStyles.eyeballImage} >
            <Image
              style={CheckInStyles.eyeballImageImage}
              source={require('../images/icons/ico-eyeball.png')}
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
  )
});
```

The brief states that on press of the touchable opacity -  the stars should switch to display the code for 5 seconds only.  I was thinking this would be easy with state - I could switch a display class on two Text objects to hide/show stars or code.  But how do I do this with fixed state if I don't know how many alarm codes there will be?  Can I use a dynamic state - is there such a thing - or does anyone have any other ideas for best approach in this situation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up your state, include a property in the objects for whether they're showing:

```
this.state = {
    alarmsOnSite: whereverYoureGettingTheDataNow.map(obj => ({...obj, showing: false})),
    // ...
};
```

Then in response to a touch, set that flag to `true` and then back to `false` after five seconds. For instance, if the touch is on the `ToucableOpacity` itself (sorry, I don't know that component):

```
  <View style={[GlobalStyles.GreyBox, {position:'relative'}]}>
    <Text style={GlobalStyles.starText}>
    {data.showing ? data.code : "********"}
    </Text>

    <TouchableOpacity
      style={CheckInStyles.eyeballImagePlacement}
      onTouch={() => this.showAlarm(data)}
    >
      <View style={CheckInStyles.eyeballImage} >
        <Image
          style={CheckInStyles.eyeballImageImage}
          source={require('../images/icons/ico-eyeball.png')}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

...where `showAlarm` is:

```
showAlarm(alarm) {
    let updated = null;
    this.setState(
        ({alarmsOnSite}) => ({
            alarmsOnSite: alarmsOnSite.map(a => {
                if (a === alarm) {
                    return updated = {...a, showing: true};
                }
                return a;
            })
        }),
        () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState(({alarmsOnSite}) => ({
                    alarmsOnSite: alarmsOnSite.map(a => a === updated ? {...a, showing: false} : a)
                }));
            }, 5000);
        }
    );
}
```

...or similar.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
const whereverYoureGettingTheDataNow = [{ location: "Main Door", code:"123456"}, { location: "Back Door", code:"456789"}];

class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            alarmsOnSite: whereverYoureGettingTheDataNow.map(obj => ({...obj, showing: false})),
            // ...
        };
    }

    showAlarm(alarm) {
        let updated = null;
        this.setState(
            ({alarmsOnSite}) => ({
                alarmsOnSite: alarmsOnSite.map(a => {
                    if (a === alarm) {
                        return updated = {...a, showing: true};
                    }
                    return a;
                })
            }),
            () => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState(({alarmsOnSite}) => ({
                        alarmsOnSite: alarmsOnSite.map(a => a === updated ? {...a, showing: false} : a)
                    }));
                }, 5000);
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.state.alarmsOnSite.map((data, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    {data.location}
                    <div onClick={() => this.showAlarm(data)}>
                        {data.showing ? data.code : "********"}
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you very much - will implement it in the morning and if all ok return to give you a tick..  Thanks again.